# How to set start value of jquery slider after jquery ajax response?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I´m having some trouble setting the initial value of my Jquery UI Slider. The main problem (I think) is that the initial value I'm setting is being generated AFTER the slider is created (the initial value is coming from a Jquery.ajax).

Here is what I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function(){
        function ReadVars() {
            $.ajax({
                //Post to fetch values from computer B
                url: "somefile.php",
                type: "post",
                datatype: "html",
                data: {
                    foo: "foo",
                    bar: "bar",
                },
                success: function(response){
                    //Computer B responds with several values separated by
                    // a comma e.g. "0,23,1,hello,etc"
                    var responseSplitted = response.split( "," );
                    //The second value from the response (in this case 23) 
                    //should be the initial value of the slider
                    var SliderStart = responseSplitted[1];
                    console.log("Slider start = ", SliderStart);
                },
            });
        }
        var Init = false;
        if( !Init ) {
            console.log( "Init" );
            Init = true;
            ReadVars();
        }
        setInterval( ReadVars, 10000 ); //Update respond every 10 seconds
        $("#slider1").slider({
            value: SliderStart,  //SliderStart should be 23.. but is not working
            //because SliderStart does not exist at the moment this part is run
            min: 0,
            max: 60,
            slide: function (event, ui) {
                $("#slider1Value").val(ui.value + " kg");
            },
            stop: function(){
                var value = $(this).slider( "option", "value" );
                console.log( "value = ", value );
            }
        });
        $( "#slider1Value" ).val( $( "#slider1" ).slider( "value" ));
    });
</script>    


<body>    
    <input id="slider1Value" type="text">
    <div id="slider1" style="width:300px;"></div>
    <input type="text" id="slider1Value" />
</body>
```

If I include the following two lines under the "success: function(response){}", then it works.

```
$( "#slider1" ).slider( "option", "value", SliderStart );
$( "#slider1Value" ).val( $( "#slider1" ).slider( "value" ) + " kg" );
```

However, I just want to set the initial value once and not every 10 seconds. Is there anyway of doing this?

Comment: You could use a bool to check if it has been initialized - so set it after it runs once, and then ignore on subsequent calls.

Comment: u have to move start slider at .success callback, or add setTimeout for few ms

Answer (score 0):

If you move all the code that creates your slider to the success function of your Ajax call, then the slider will be created as soon as your initial value is available.